How do I find out the version of clang-format in CLion?
Given the same .clang-format, the clang-format in CLion behaves differently than the one installed in the OS (Debian clang-format version 14.0.6), I suspect CLion is using   clang-format of another version, but how do I find out which version is it?
CLion verion: 2024.2.2
ClangConfig: bundled 242.21829.173
